# Como especificar el máximo de objetos dentro de un array?

Tags: javascript

***Suponiendo que tengo lo siguiente:***

```
var Ob = {

cells: [{},{},{},{}]

};
```

Como podría limitar el límite en dos casos:

1) Limitar solamente a n cantidades el límite de `OBJETOS` que se pueden introducir al `array`

2) Limitar *cualquier elemento* a n cantidades que se pueden introducir al `array`

Comment: Me parece que en JavaScript no hay una opción por defecto para conseguir esto como en otros lenguajes, ¿está bien si el límite realmente se impone/comprueba al insertar un nuevo elemento?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38242954/4305494

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, no se puede hacer eso en javascript, o sea le puedes asignar una cantidad de elementos, pero no limitarlo.

La solución para ello sería que te creases un método que cada vez que agregases elementos al array compruebe la longitud y si sobra algo lo corte.

Por ejemplo:

```
arrayPropio.splice(4, 1)
```

Esto elimina 1 único elemento en la posición 4 del array (según tu ejemplo sólo quieres que contenga 4 elementos, de la posición 0 a la 3, por lo tanto si compruebas al introducir y supera el número máximo que hayas establecido lo borra). Quedaría un ejemplo así. ([Documentación Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice))

```
if (arrayPropio.length >= 5) {
      arrayPropio.splice(4, 1)
    }
```

Otra manera de hacerlo sería utilizando:

```
arrayPropio.slice(0,4)
```

Esto te devuelve siempre las posiciones entre la 0 y la 3 (los 4 primeros elementos). El ejemplo sería así: ([Documentación Slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice))

```
if (arrayPropio.length >= 5) {
          arrayPropio.splice(4, 1)
        }
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda, saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Los Arrays en JavaScript son dinámicos, por lo cual siempre se podra agregar un número "infinito" de elementos en un arreglo,

Lo que te recomendaría para este caso es usar condicionales para que un arreglo solo mantenga un numero determinado de elementos.

ejemplo

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
```

supongamos que queremos mantener estos 4 elementos.

```
if (arr.length >= 5){
arr.splice(arr.length-1,1);
}
```

el método splice()actualiza el array que lo llama, así siempre tendrías 4 elementos, los parámetros que se pasan es el tamaño del array menos 1 (recordando que los indices de un arreglo comienzan desde 0) y la cantidad de elementos que quieres eliminar (como estamos en el ultimo elemento solo pondríamos 1).

Answer (score 0):

Buenas.
Yo lo que haría sería lo siguiente.
Crearía un array vacío y una constante para definir el tamaño.De la siguiente forma.

```
 const TAM = 5;//constante que define mi tamanio
 cells = new Array();//array vacio
```

Cuando quieras añadir objetos al array solo tienes que controlar que la longitud del array no sea superior a la constante.

```
    if (cells.length < TAM) {
       cells.unshift(objeto);
     }
```

De esta forma si la longitud del array es mayor o igual que la constante no inserta elementos.